# Using a link to connect two pages in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page with a search bar that gets images of people in alphabetical order from a database. I also have a page with Next and Previous buttons that allows the user to browse through the database of images using Next and Previous buttons. I'm trying figure out a way to make an image a link so that the user can search through images, click the image, and it takes them to the same image on the Next and Previous page.

This is my code that allows me to search and returns, lastname, firstname, and a picture:

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <?php
     if (isset($_GET['LastName'])) {
 $ln = $_GET['LastName'];
 }
        include 'connection.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE LastName like '$ln%' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div class="media col-sm-4">
        <a class="pull-left" href="Browse.php">
    <img class="media-object" src="upload/<?php echo $person['Picture'];?>" width="100"
    height="100"/>
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
     <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $person['LastName'] . ", " .   
$person['FirstName']; ?></h4>

   </div>
```

The page I'm trying to connect to is "Browse.php" but as you browse through the images the URL changes by increasing..."Browse.php?page=1"..."Browse.php?page=2" and so on. Is there an easy way to connect an image with the corresponding Browse.php page? I've tried several things and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try to use person id?

Answer (score 0):

If you have id column in residents table. You can do something like this.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page_id = $_GET['page'];
 }
 include 'connection.php';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE ID = $page_id";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<div class="media col-sm-4">
    <a class="pull-left" href="Browse.php?page=<?php echo $page_id; ?>">
         <img class="media-object" src="upload/<?php echo $person['Picture'];?>" width="100" height="100"/>
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
     <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $person['LastName'] . ", " .   $person['FirstName']; ?></h4>
    </div>
</div>   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When I use this method all of the data that was returned disappears. I think it's because I'm searching all the images by LastName and not by the ID. I'm working with the idea of using the ID to connect the images to the Browse page but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Can you tell me the structure of your residents table?

Comment: I tried the code you updated but still no luck. There are 12 columns titled: ID, FirstName, LastName, Address, Birthday, FormerResidence, Career, Education, MaritalStatus, Siblings, SpecialInterests, Picture. On the search page, all the is drawn from the DB is FirstName, LastName, and Picture.

Comment: Maybe then you can try and update this  line. 
$query = "SELECT * FROM residents WHERE ID = $page_id";